# PHP header redirect not working on Apache

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

This is my first question here, and I will try to follow all the advice I received when I signed up...

My problem is the 'headers sent' error when trying to do a PHP redirect.

I have this tiny script to test a redirect:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['go']) && $_POST['go'] == 'go') {
$redirectURL = 'test1.php'; 
header( 'Location: ' . $redirectURL ) ;
exit();
}
echo '<p>This is Page 1. We will test a redirect. Type in \'go\' and hit submit:</p><br><br>';
echo '<form name="test" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';  
echo '<input type="text" name="go">';   
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
echo '</form>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It redirects fine when run on a Windows server, but on an Apache it gives the error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/simply92/public_html/test/testUTF.php:7) in /home/simply92/public_html/test/testUTF.php on line 10

Line 7 is the php tag.

I used my web host's code editor to save with encoding ISO-8859-1 (which should get any BOMs out of the equation, right?) and I set the default charset in php.ini to ISO-8859-1 as well (in case that matters.)

One strange thing is that it redirects even on the Apache when I delete doctype and everthing else up to the php tag and have my very first line in the script be `<?php`. Obviously that can not be the solution.

So my question is: How could I find out WHAT is being sent before my header() call, and then, how could I get rid of it?

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's header requires that the output buffer is free from any other data.  The headers must be set before the doctype, head and body tags printed.  This should work

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['go']) && $_POST['go'] == 'go') {
$redirectURL = 'test1.php'; 
header( 'Location: ' . $redirectURL ) ;
exit();
}
?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo '<p>This is Page 1. We will test a redirect. Type in \'go\' and hit submit:</p><br><br>';
echo '<form name="test" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';  
echo '<input type="text" name="go">';   
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
echo '</form>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most famous errors for php, you can make a [search on Google for explanations](http://www.google.it/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Cannot%20modify%20header%20information)

In your case your code is wrong because you DO a lot of output before the `header` call. In windows it just works because you likely have the output buffering turned on and you haven't it in Apache.

You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), but I really advise you to change your code, the `header` function should be called only if you haven't sent any output to the browser, you can check for it by using the [header_sent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function.

Comment: I WILL change my code. I just hadn't realized that doctype etc counts as output. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, thanks also for pointing out the bit about output buffering. It's a good feeling to understand what's going on.